# Trying To Add Obtained Guid To an obtained SID to a Remote Registry Key in Powershell to Multiple Remote Laptops

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to add a Guid which I have obtained from AD on to a number of remote users.  I have got the Guid and the SID from Profilelist within the registry but each time I try and complete it I get the incorrect path and I cannot find a way to word this to Google it better.

I have the following in Powershell:

```
$user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the user name'
$guid = Get-ADUser $user -Properties * | Select ObjectGUID
$sid = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($user)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).value
$regpath = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\'
$profilepath = $sid
$fullpath = $regpath + $profilepath
$credential = Get-Credential -Credential doman\admin.account
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName laptopnumber -Credential $credential
New-Item -Path $path3 -Name Test -Value '14'
```

When I Write-Output for $fullpath I get the exact path I would expect.  However, when I run the script I get the following error:

```
New-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\nameofaccountIamusing\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-1810327472-1994124132-3348413286-12785\Test'.
At line:9 char:1
+ New-Item -Path $fullpath -Name Test -Value '14'
```

I cannot work this out.  Any advice hugely appreciated. I don't see why it is adding in the C:\Users\nameofaccountIamusing

Comment: Try with `$regpath = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\'. You forgot to add the **registry provider** in front of the path and without that, the system will try and find a path on the disk
`

Comment: Hello @Theo thank you very much.  That seems to be what I am missing with that error.  However, I have noticed that I am now not getting the SID from the remote machine, but from my own.  So a lot more Googling for me.  Thanks for getting past this error though.

Comment: @Theo thanks already but do you know if I could do $regpath = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ + $sid?

Comment: No way of telling because you don't show us enough code.. Where does `$user` come from an what is `$path3` ?

Comment: @Theo sorry I have changed the $path3 to $fullpath in the code.  $user will be from my input

Comment: Hello @Theo you can put your comment as the answer, as that has resolved that issue for me. Thanks

Comment: Sure, will do in a minute ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that you forgot to add the **registry provider** in front of the path and without that, the system will try and find a path on the disk.

Instead of

```
$regpath = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\'
```

use

```
$regpath = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList'
```

or <sup>(*)</sup>

```
$regpath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList'
```

I would also advise to use the `Join-Path` cmdlet for concatenating parts to create a full path.

Because `Get-ADUser` by default returns objects with these properties: `DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName`, there is no need to first fetch the `ObjectGUID` and from that figure out the users SID.

Just do `$adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$user'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and if that returns an object, you can get the SID like this: `$adUser.SID`

<sup>(*)
When using PowerShell < 7, the `Set-ItemProperty` cmdlet to create a new registry value **cannot handle** the `-Type` parameter when using the short `HKLM:` provider path..
This *does* however work when using `Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`</sup>